# css firebug where is this negative position coming from

Tags: firefox, firebug, css

i have an element with the following css attributes:

```
 .myElem {
   position:absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 25px;
   height:6px;
   padding: 1px 0px;
}
```

please see this screen shot i uploaded [image]
when looking at the layout tab of the firebug inspection....i noticed the '-13' at the bottom...where is it from? what does it mean? i did not specify it...why is it showing there? what does it tell me about 'bottom'? or it means something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's show position from **bottom** in **minus** if the position from top overlap or more than his parent.

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/wqrh6/

in this when `.myElem` position top overlap his **parent** then the firebug show position from **bottom**

Comment: bottom of who though?  say screen shot above, -13 means based on parent element or the element it self...-13 from parents bottom?

Comment: it's means if you give position from bottom -13px it's show same as if you give position from top 25px.